# Amazon simple notification service (SNS) - How to publish a message to specify endpoint by its arn or token

Tags: android, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm developing a system that will push notification to mobile devices, I'm building an asp.net web api application as a server which will register mobile devices to aws sns as endpoints of a platform application with their token from Firebase massaging service, I've already successfully published messages to mobile devices using aws sns console,But I can't find any documentation that would guide me to implement it with asp.net server.I've already done the register and create endpoint parts from aws console document like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void RegisterWithSNS(TokenAuth tokenAuth)
    {
        String endpointArn = EndpointArn;
        String applicationArn = "arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:my arn from platform application console";

        bool updateNeeded = false;
        bool createNeeded = (null == endpointArn);

        if (createNeeded)
        {
            // No platform endpoint ARN is stored; need to call createEndpoint.
            EndpointArn = CreateEndpoint(tokenAuth.token, applicationArn);
            createNeeded = false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving platform endpoint data...");
        // Look up the platform endpoint and make sure the data in it is current, even if
        // it was just created.
        try
        {
            GetEndpointAttributesRequest geaReq = new GetEndpointAttributesRequest();
            geaReq.EndpointArn = EndpointArn;
            GetEndpointAttributesResponse geaRes = client.GetEndpointAttributes(geaReq);
            updateNeeded = !(geaRes.Attributes["Token"] == tokenAuth.token) || !(geaRes.Attributes["Enabled"] == "true");
        }
        catch (NotFoundException)
        {
            // We had a stored ARN, but the platform endpoint associated with it
            // disappeared. Recreate it.
            createNeeded = true;
        }

        if (createNeeded)
        {
            CreateEndpoint(tokenAuth.token, applicationArn);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("updateNeeded = " + updateNeeded);

        if (updateNeeded)
        {
            // The platform endpoint is out of sync with the current data;
            // update the token and enable it.
            Console.WriteLine("Updating platform endpoint " + endpointArn);
            Dictionary<String, String> attribs = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            attribs["Token"] = tokenAuth.token;
            attribs["Enabled"] = "true";
            SetEndpointAttributesRequest saeReq = new SetEndpointAttributesRequest();
            saeReq.EndpointArn = EndpointArn;
            saeReq.Attributes = attribs;
            client.SetEndpointAttributes(saeReq);
        }
    }

    private String CreateEndpoint(String token, String applicationArn)
    {
        String endpointArn = null;

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating platform endpoint with token " + token);
            CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
            cpeReq.PlatformApplicationArn = applicationArn;
            cpeReq.Token = token;
            CreatePlatformEndpointResponse cpeRes = client.CreatePlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
            endpointArn = cpeRes.EndpointArn;
        }
        catch (InvalidParameterException ipe)
        {
            String message = ipe.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("Exception message: " + message);
            Regex rgx = new Regex(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists with the same [Tt]oken.*",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection m = rgx.Matches(message);
            if (m.Count > 0 && m[0].Groups.Count > 1)
            {
                // The platform endpoint already exists for this token, but with
                // additional custom data that createEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite.
                // Just use the existing platform endpoint.
                endpointArn = m[0].Groups[1].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                // Rethrow the exception, the input is actually bad.
                throw ipe;
            }
        }
        EndpointArn = endpointArn;
        return endpointArn;
    }
```

And on mobile device(android) I also done implement the "get token from firebase" and call RegisterWithSNS(TokenAuth tokenAuth) on my server api, but now I don't know how to publish a message to a specify endpoint by using endpoint token or arn.
Could anyone please show me how could it be done?

Comment: I think you can just call `Publish()` and specify a `TargetArn`: [Publish - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html)

Comment: @John Rotenstein: I'll give it a try, I think it would work

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : It's working,you should put your comment as an answer

Comment: this is how I implement it: public bool PublishMessage(AWSClientModel aWSClientModel)
        {
            PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
            publishRequest.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aWSClientModel.Notification);
            publishRequest.TargetArn = aWSClientModel.EndpointArn;
            PublishResponse publishResponse = client.Publish(publishRequest);
            if (publishResponse.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

Comment: You are welcome to add an Answer to your own question. (It looks better that way, too!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on @John Rotenstein comment on my question, I just implemented it myself just like bellow:

```
    public bool PublishMessage(AWSClientModel aWSClientModel) { 
           PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(); 
           publishRequest.Message =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aWSClientModel.Notification); 
           publishRequest.TargetArn = aWSClientModel.EndpointArn;
           PublishResponse publishResponse = client.Publish(publishRequest); 
           if (publishResponse.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) { 
             return true; 
           } 
          return false; 
     }
```